# Beginner Ruby - about Objects

Tags: ruby

Beginner on Ruby here...below are two similar codes, I understand the procedures of this very basic code but I'd like to understand the theory behind it...

First

```
 def stats(ppg)
   if ppg > 20
     puts "The PG is considered elite"
   else
     puts "The PG is not considered elite"
   end
 end

 stats(28)
```

Second

```
 def stats(ppg)
   if ppg > 20
     "The PG is considered elite"
   else
     "The PG is not considered elite"
   end
 end

 puts stats(28)
```

So the first piece automatically writes out the strings whereas the second piece does not - is stats(ppg) from the first piece considered an object or a method with the variable as the argument?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: nothing wrong with the code, just trying to understand the subtle nuances of both ways

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong. Glad you got your answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def stats(ppg)` in both cases is the same thing, i.e. the beginning of a method definition for a method named `stats` that takes one argument or parameter that will be named `ppg` inside the method body.

`stats(28)` in both cases is the same thing, i.e. a call to a method named `stats` with the literal Fixnum `28` passed as its argument, whereupon it will be assigned to the variable `ppg` inside the method body from the definition.

In Ruby, every expression involves two distinct phenomena: side effects, and return values. The expression `a = 1` has a side effect of assigning the value of `1` to the variable `a`, and a return value of `1`. Not every method in Ruby has a side effect, but every method does have a return value — either an explicit return value (by using `return`), or else the return value of the last expression evaluated in the method body.

`puts` is an unfortunate method in Ruby, because it is used in so many beginner examples, yet its behavior is confusing. It has a side effect of printing its argument to stdout, but its return value is `nil` (which often confuses beginners, who expect it to return the value of its argument).

The difference between your first method and second method is that the first method, because it uses `puts` internally, has the side effect of printing a string to stdout and a return value of `nil`, while the second method has no side effect, but a return value of the string itself.

Therefore, when you call your first method without `puts` in front, the side effect of printing the string occurs and you see the output. When you call your second method, there is no printing side effect, so in order to have the string printed to stdout, you have to call `puts`. The argument to `puts` is the return value of your `stats` method, i.e. the string you wanted to print.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer... and since you mentioned puts - I can't reference the literature but came across in a book a longer way to write out the method (so as to illustrate R's programming concept and the operative behavior) - would you happen to know of the alternative method to writing puts? Or a reference?

Comment: `puts` is useful in many cases. It is the best way to write an entire line to a stream, such as stdout (`$stdout.puts(my_string)`), stderr (`$stderr.puts(my_string)`), or an open file handler (`File.open('somefile.txt','w') {|f| f.puts('my_string') }`). The crucial thing to remember is that it returns `nil`. A common mistake when trying to print a value for debugging purposes is to add a `puts` in front of the final line of a method body (i.e. the implicit return value), forgetting that this changes the return value of the method to `nil` as well. Try using `p`, which returns the value itself.